# Polynomials and Limits

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $P(x)$ be any polynomial with positive real coefficients. Determine the following limit with proof

$ \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\lfloor P(x) \rfloor}{P(\lfloor x \rfloor)}$

**I am unable to approach these kind of sums. Anyone please can guide me and help me with this solution?**

Answer (score 2):

Here, we assume $P(x)$ is nonconstant. Your limit is equal to, for some $a,b\in[0, 1)$ ($a$ and $b$ are also functions of $x$):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{P(x) - a}{P(x - b)}$$

Note that we can rearrange this as:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{P(x) - a}{P(x)}\frac{P(x)}{P(x-b)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{P(x) - a}{P(x)}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{P(x)}{P(x - b)}$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigg(1 - \frac{a}{P(x)}\bigg)\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{P(x)}{P(x-b)}$$

Then, since $P(x)$ has positive coefficients and is nonconstant, $P(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$. Thus, since $a$ is bounded:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigg(1 - \frac{a}{P(x)}\bigg)\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{P(x)}{P(x-b)} = \bigg(1 - \frac{a}{\infty}\bigg)\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{P(x)}{P(x-b)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{P(x)}{P(x-b)}$$

Then, taking $x$ at the integers, which are also unbounded in the positive direction, we find that $b = 0$, so:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{P(x)}{P(x-b)}=\lim_{x\to\infty, x\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{P(x)}{P(x-b)} = \lim_{x\to\infty, x\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{P(x)}{P(x)} = 1$$
Thus:

$$\boxed{\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor P(x)\rfloor}{P(\lfloor x\rfloor)} = 1}$$

In the case of the constant function $P(x) = p$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor P(x)\rfloor}{P(\lfloor x\rfloor)} = \frac{\lfloor p\rfloor}{p}$, which is not always equal to $1$.

Comment: Thank you. In the last line, you meant constant function right? Which is not always equal to 1?

Comment: Oops! Edited, thanks.

Comment: I am unable to understand, how you took P(x)-b in the denominator. Since the floor function is inside the brackets, shouldn't it be P(x-b)?

Comment: Can you please explain the b=0 part?

Comment: When $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, $\lfloor x\rfloor = x$, which means $b = x-\lfloor x\rfloor = 0$. We can use the integers for our limit instead of all real numbers, because for any real number, there is always a greater or equal integer.